# How do I disable the <Enter> after the scan when using Esky Barcode Scanner?

Tags: web, barcode-scanner

I have a Esky USB Barcode Reader, Model 261-0300-01.

After the scan, it adds an <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the application continues. I would like it to input *just* the scan without the <kbd>Enter</kbd> so I can see/edit the information scanned into a web based input form.

Comment: The scanner is esky model 261-0300-01 –

Answer (score 1):

The rather sparse manual has many barcodes in it that you just scan to set the various options.

Some codes(no idea what barcode format it uses, or if there are pre or post control codes embedded in it) are:

```
0A - Display frimware rev 
0B - Reset unit to factory default
0B20201 - Disable adding CR or LF to scan
0202011000$0D - Add CR to scan
0202011000$0A - Add LF to scan
0202011000$0D$0A - Add CR+LF to scan
0202001020$09 - Add TAB to Code39 scans
0B202001020$09 - Disable adding TAB to code39 scans
```

So if you can figure out which barcode format to print those out in, then just scan the barcodes for

```
0B20201
```

then

```
0B202001020$09.
```

If you really need it, I could scan the manual for you.

Answer (score 0):

At least some of the more pricey Datalogic scanners may be configured using barcodes presented in their manual.
As you did not define the actual model, I could not locate a manual to peek into. ("esk" = "esky"?)

**Addition:**
http://www.neweggbusiness.com/product/product.aspx?item=9b-16p-0007-00003
Mfr. Part #: 261-00301-05-001
$29.99 <del>$55.99</del> Save: $26.00 (46%)

Not likely to be configurable.
As always: Buy a cheap product and pay the price with having to stick with its available settings.

More capable products http://www.datalogic.com/ - many of which can be configured for almost any task.
Downside: They cost more.

Comment: The scanner is esky model 261-0300-01

Comment: Updated with found info.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Calvin's earlier response - most barcode scanners use Code 128 barcodes for their management and configuration setup.  They generally also include a prefix of  which is not always obvious when you try reading the barcode with another brand of scanner.  But best to get a copy of the manual for this one.

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment. Please have patience and work on gaining rep by answer other questions and then you would be able to comment soon